# It's running fine on my local pc but why it is causing error in Leetcode I can't understand?

Tags: python

You are given two integer arrays nums1 and nums2, sorted in non-decreasing order, and two integers m and n, representing the number of elements in nums1 and nums2 respectively.

Merge nums1 and nums2 into a single array sorted in non-decreasing order.

The final sorted array should not be returned by the function, but instead be stored inside the array nums1. To accommodate this, nums1 has a length of m + n, where the first m elements denote the elements that should be merged, and the last n elements are set to 0 and should be ignored. nums2 has a length of n.

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """

        if len(nums1) == 0:
            for i in range(len(nums2)):
                nums1.append(nums2[i])
                
        i, j = 0, 0

        templist = []

        while i < m and j < n:
            if nums1[i] < nums2[j]:
                templist.append(nums1[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                templist.append(nums2[j])
                j += 1

        for k in range(len(nums1)):
            nums1[k] = templist[k]

        while i < m:
            nums1.append(nums1[i])
            i += 1
        while j < n:
            nums1.append(nums2[j])
            j += 1
```

Error:

````
IndexError: list index out of range
    nums1[k] = templist[k]
Line 24 in merge (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().merge(param_1, param_2, param_3, param_4)
Line 66 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 78 in <module> (Solution.py)```

it's running fine on my local pc then why the error in leetcode?
````

Comment: Did you pay attention to the part that says "To accommodate this, nums1 has a length of m + n, where the first m elements denote the elements that should be merged, and the last n elements are set to 0 and should be ignored."?

Answer (score 0):

Your `templist` is not in general the same length as `nums1` (it's shorter, that's why you need to extend it with `nums1` or `nums2` in the end to get the "whole" list merged).

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two input lists. Sort them. Place result in the first of the input lists:

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        nums1[:] = sorted(nums1[:m]+nums2[:n])
```

Comment: That's not what the leetcode is for. If you use `sorted`, then you don't need to implement merge(sort) at all. In fact you never do and it's a useless thing to ask, but still...

Comment: @Gameplay I don't get your point. My answer fulfils the brief. There are no stated constraints within the question as posted here. Of course, there may be on Leetcode but that's irrelevant